# Disable password authentication on mounting a device

Tags: permissions, mount, root

I'm using Debian linux. When ever I try to mount a NTFS HDD, it asks password to root. How can I give root permission permanently?[image]

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look into `pmount`

`pmount` ("policy mount") is a wrapper around the standard mount program which permits normal users to mount removable devices without a matching /etc/fstab entry.

In this case it sounds like you would want to use the `-p` flag: If the device is encrypted (dm-crypt with LUKS metadata), read the passphrase from specified file instead of prompting at the terminal.

Instead of prompting you every time it mounts, it will instead consult the passphrase file and mount silently.

Comment: I do not think the question is about the encryption, but the password to mount the hard drive.

Answer (score 0):

Old question but pops up in searches: the simplest GUI solution (tested in Debian-based and RH-based systems, I think it works allover Linux): Gnome Disks.

[image]

[image]